# Constructing std::ifstream with a std::string_view working on mac but nowhere else

Tags: c++, constructor, ifstream, std, string-view

A few days ago, I wrote this simple function to read from a text file

```
std::string readFile(std::string_view path) {
    std::ifstream file(path);
    
    if(file) {
        std::stringstream contents;
        
        contents << file.rdbuf();
        
        return contents.str();
    }
    
    std::stringstream error;
    
    error << path << " could not be found";
    
    throw std::invalid_argument(error.str());
}
```

It compiled and worked just fine on my mac. However, I was making something on replit instead of on my computer and used the same function, but this time I got a compiler error.

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>')
    std::ifstream file(path);
                  ^    ~~~~
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/fstream:529:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>') to 'const char *' for 1st argument
      basic_ifstream(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
      ^
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/fstream:562:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>') to 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
      basic_ifstream(const std::string& __s,
      ^
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/fstream:585:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>') to 'const std::basic_ifstream<char>' for 1st argument
      basic_ifstream(const basic_ifstream&) = delete;
      ^
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/fstream:587:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string_view' (aka 'basic_string_view<char>') to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>' for 1st argument
      basic_ifstream(basic_ifstream&& __rhs)
      ^
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/fstream:579:2: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Path = std::basic_string_view<char>]: no member named 'make_preferred' in 'std::basic_string_view<char>'
        basic_ifstream(const _Path& __s,
        ^
/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/fstream:518:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
      basic_ifstream() : __istream_type(), _M_filebuf()
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Which was really weird, since it worked on my computer.

So I tried using various other online compilers, both gcc and clang, and they all showed a very similar error message.

Why is this only working on my machine? Is it something to do with macOS?

Comment: Which constructor is called on your machine? `std::fstream` doesn't take `std::string_view` for a reason. `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, but an underlying OS API function almost certainly expects a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Evg The one that accepts a `const std::filesystem::path&`. It seems it's doing an implicit conversion.

Comment: It looks like your implementation of the standard library (which one?) has an overload that takes `std::filesystem::path` directly. However, cppreference [doesn't list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) such a constructor.

Comment: @Evg That's weird. Why would they do that? About the implementation, I'm using whatever the default one on mac is. If it helps, at the beginning of all of the files it says something about the "LLVM Project".

Comment: @Evg I just found something! On the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) it lists the conversion as [a defect](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3430) that was "avoided by making it a template". So maybe for whatever reason my implementation didn't do that?

Comment: Maybe it's simply somewhat outdated.

Comment: @Evg I'm pretty sure I have the latest version of Xcode, 14.1...

Comment: @Evg Is there some way I can report this to LLVM so it can be fixed?

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

Comment: @Evg Thanks! Created an issue https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/59029.